# LEFT JOIN with ORDER BY and CASE

Tags: mysql

I want to get the results from the userdata table with order by fro the left join, its run but its order wrong.

```
SELECT 
u.id,
u.name,
f.tstamp
FROM userdata AS u
LEFT JOIN messages AS f ON (u.id=f.user_id) OR (u.id=f.friend_id)
WHERE u.id IN 
    (
        SELECT CASE 
        WHEN user_id='".$uid."' 
        THEN friend_id
        ELSE user_id
        END FROM `friends` 
        WHERE 
        (
            user_id='".$uid."' or friend_id = '".$uid."'
        ) 
        and type=2
    ) 
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY f.tstamp ASC, u.onl DESC, u.name
```

userdata > all Users

friends > Friends (1 row per 2 users)

messages > rows up to 400

so, the snipped runs but its use the oldest tstamp (timestamp) from the row not the newest.

Comment: Try `f.tstamp DESC` rather than `ASC`.

Comment: generally, sql questions go to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ordering the `timestamp` ASC which mean the highest value first. In the case of a `timestamp` it will be less recent first

Instead try `ORDER BY f.tstamp DESC`

Also I think you want to select `max(f.tstamp)` instead of `f.tstamp`

Comment: you used `order by f.tstamps desc` and the result is the same ?

Comment: i know thats confused but is it... this timestamp 1423592380 is coming but i want this 1423592409 ....

Comment: hm... this 1423592409 is higher as 1423592380 oO

Comment: please do it ... im totally confused ... i dont know why i get the oldest

Comment: if i delete the group by then the first ouput are the newest, i think this is the problem...

Comment: that gives me all rows but not the grouped by, but the right order by lol

Comment: keep the `group by` and try to select `max(f.tstamp)'  instead of just f.tstamp